# How to tell Azure not to remove particular server during scale down

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET app running on Azure App Service.
The auto-scale is setup and sometimes it goes up to 10 instances and then back to 3.

I have a background task (hangfire) that runs every hour on one of the instances (I don't know on which one, it is random).

Is there a way to tell Azure, during scale down, not to remove the server where the task is currently executing on?

Comment: You need to design your background tasks to shutdown gracefully and pick up from place where it left, also you will need to use cancellation token, because when scale down is occurred it will give your app some time to complete the job, if its not complete thread will be killed

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat do you have a link with more info about CancellationToken on Azure App Service? I could not find anything to Azure. If I can receive a notification from Azure that it is going to shutdown an instance, I can reschedule the currently executing task.

Comment: Well its not azure specific is more async specific http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html

Comment: Also for azure functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#cancellation-tokens

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat so basically for the hangfire case, I should put: cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); before each logical step of the task. 
For example: 
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
// download the file from remote server and parse it
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
// for each line of the file 
{ 
   cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
 //do work on that line
}

sound correct?

Comment: Yes, I event thing that hangfire will handle reschedule, but I am not sure here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never rely on such thing but design your background job processors to be able to shutdown gracefully.

This is why you should be using cancellation tokens in you jobs, and job should be able to pick up from where it left.

For hangfire there is [custom implementation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html). In some other cases you can use .net [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#cancellation-tokens)